# Smoothing "font characters" outlines in bitmap image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, ocr

Adobe Acrobat has this as a feature called [ClearScan](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2009/05/better_pdf_ocr_clearscan_is_smal/). While doing OCR it allows image enhancement, by smoothing irregularities on font outlines.

For example, this source:

[image]

turns to this:

[image]

Are there other tools with such feature, or public algorithms (Matlab/Python) that can smooth contours of arbitrary font-like objects?

Comment: There's an open-source command-line program called [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) that you might try.  It converts bitmaps to bezier curves and has a bunch of options allowing you to trade off smoothness and accuracy.  It's also built in to the Inkscape vector editor (under the Path -> Trace Bitmap menu option).

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking the same. If you can make your comment as answer, I'll accept it. Further to your idea, we can use Google's tesseract to segment, classify, recognize and store bounding box positions for all characters and then use potrace on just the set, so that it will be same workflow as Acrobat is doing, but with freedom to make adjustments. Acrobat is storing results in CID font and use it make PDF, while we can think about something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the open-source command-line program [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/), might do what you want.  It converts bitmaps to bezier curves and has a bunch of options allowing you to trade off smoothness and accuracy.

The open-source [Inkscape vector (svg) editor](http://inkscape.org/) has potrace built in (under the Path->Trace Bitmap menu option.)  The result of applying your example in Inkscape, (I used the mode Inkscape calls "Brightness cutoff" with the default threshold of .45, since your image was already black-and-white rather than grayscale) scaling the size of the resulting bezier curves up a bit, and then having Inkscape output a bitmap is:

[image]

One of the cute side-effects of converting to bezier and then back to grayscale is that you get nice anti-aliasing around the curves.

With grayscale input images I find that the "Edge detection" mode works a little better.  There are also options for choosing less or more smoothing, and less or more speckle elimination.